# Is there a way to have a syntax that highlight single specific words in vim?

Tags: c, vim

I want to make malloc, calloc, realloc and free bright red. That way I'll find my memory leaks easier. 
I have only found how to highlight groups, but not single words.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html

Comment: I would venture to suggest that the use of valgrind or a similar tool will make your life easier in this respect than highlighting syntax :)

Comment: Aside: I believe (but not used) that Notepad++ has a [rule-based highlight feature](https://superuser.com/questions/220815/notepad-rule-based-line-highlighting).

Comment: @KevinBoone I'm using valgrind as well. Want to highlight it to lower the use of valgrind

Comment: Use also some address sanitizer, e.g. `-fsanitize=address` [instrumentation option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) to `gcc`